# Remove Specific svg in d3

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I have a page, with multiple types of d3 graphs/charts and for each chart I have used 1 svg.
Now, whenever I do:

```
d3.select("svg").remove();
```

all the svgs, for all the charts are getting removed.
Is there any way to remove specific svgs for specific charts ?

Comment: Use IDs on your SVGs or something else, that identifies them *uniquely*. As an alternative you could keep the reference to the SVGs, after you create them.

Comment: Even if I'll use different id for different svg, once I'll call d3.select("svg").remove() for some chart inside some id-based condition, it'll remove all the svgs

Comment: If you have an ID, you should use the ID to select the element and not the general tag selector: `d3.select( '#myID' ).remove()`.

Answer (score 0):

Just add class for different charts and remove it using the class instead of removing the entire graph. If you have any doubts in this please share your code. we can solve it.